# How to run code in only for selected checkboxes in pyqt5?

Tags: checkbox, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a menu GUI using pyqt5, the menu includes drinks and other stuff.
In front of each menu item there is a checkbox, when it is checked its price will be added to the bill.

```
self.latte_box = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)   #latte_box is the name of the checkbox
self.latte_box.setText("")
self.latte_box.setObjectName("latte_box")
self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.latte_box)
    
self.latte_box.stateChanged.connect(self.order)


self.cookie_box = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3)
self.cookie_box.setText("")
self.cookie_box.setObjectName("cookie_box")
self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.cookie_box)

self.cookie_box.stateChanged.connect(self.order)    


bill = 0   #the bill variable
def order(self):
   if self.latte_box.isChecked():
      bill += 2.85
   else:
      bill -= 2.85

   if self.cookie_box.isChecked():
      bill += 1.50
   else:
      bill -= 1.50
```

latte_box and cookie_box are the checkboxes of 2 items on the list with the prices of $2.85 and $1.50.
So when the user check the box, the price of the item will be added to the bill, but in case of an error the user will just uncheck the box and the price of the item will be removed from the bill.

The problem here is that all the items run through the method (order), and whether the box is checked the price is added, and if its not checked the price is removed.

How can only the boxes that are checked or unchecked run through the method, and the untouched ones remain still.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.latte_box = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()   
        self.latte_box.setText("2.85")
        self.latte_box.stateChanged.connect(lambda state, cb=self.latte_box: self.order(state, cb))


        self.cookie_box = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        self.cookie_box.setText("1.50")
        self.cookie_box.stateChanged.connect(lambda state, cb=self.cookie_box: self.order(state, cb))  

        self.label = QLabel()        
        
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.latte_box, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cookie_box, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0)

        self.bill = 0   
        
    def order(self, state, cb):
        if cb is self.latte_box:     
            if state:
                self.bill += 2.85
            else:
                self.bill -= 2.85          
        elif cb is self.cookie_box:        
            if state:
                self.bill += 1.50
            else:
                self.bill -= 1.50  
                
        self.label.setText(f'{abs(self.bill):.2f}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Window()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: it worked for the first 2 times i checked then unchecked the checkboxes, and then numbers start mixing with each others

Comment: @Pulse  Have you tried my example? Does my example work incorrectly for you? or have you made any changes to your program, the result of which you described in the comment above?

Comment: i tried your example, it worked fine for the first 2 consecutive "check/uncheck" the boxes, then i saw that the problem wasnt your example, for some reason the compiler is making errors on a decimal level so the solution was to round the bill for 2 decimals after the comma by using " round(bill, 2) "